# Avoid duplicates using foreach asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a tab where one adds their products and automatically it will add it on the tab. But now my issue is that it repeats the same thing on the tab view "header" whenever I have uploaded the same database. I want it to categorize it and not repeat it. Below is the code I have created.

The picture below shows the database.
[image]

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
```

View

```
    @model IEnumerable<tkkkk.Models.Product>
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

       int counterHeader = 0;
       int counterBody = 0;
     }
    <br />
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        
        if (counterHeader == 0)
        {
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#@product.ProductId">@product.ProductName</a></li>
        }

        else
        {
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#@product.ProductId">@product.ProductName</a></li>
        }
        counterHeader++;
    }
   </ul>
   <br />

   <div class="tab-content">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    if (counterBody == 0)
    {
        <div id="@item.ProductId" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" style="width:200px;">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="" width="200"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <a href="#">@item.ProductItem - @item.ProductName</a>
                        </h4>
                        <h5>R @item.ProductPrice</h5>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    else
    {
        <div id="@item.ProductId" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" style="width:200px;">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="" width="200"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <a href="#">@item.ProductItem - @item.ProductName</a>
                        </h4>
                        <h5>R @item.ProductPrice</h5>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            }
            counterBody++;
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no update of `counterBody` inside `if (counterBody == 0)`

Comment: How do I add the "update"?